# How to correctly server a file from Azure Storage using a dotnet core controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I have a controller in my dotnet core web application to fetch a resource from a Azure storage account in Azure and offer it to the user for download. The user can't directly access the Azure storage account, so my webapp works as a proxy and authenticates the user before service the file.

My doubt is if my implementation if efficient with large files? My concern is that DownloadToStreamAsync() actually fetches the entire file in the memory of the webapp before serving it.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Serve(string path)
{
    MemoryStream streamIn = null;
    CloudFile file = null;
    Stream fileStream = null;
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(path);

    // application-level permission checks checks
    
    // fetching file from Azure Storage
    try {
        var storageConnectionString = _azureOptions.AzureStorageAccountConnectionString;
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        var fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        var share = fileClient.GetShareReference(_azureOptions.AzureStorageAccountContentShareName);
        var root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        file = root.GetFileReference(path);
        if (!await file.ExistsAsync())
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        streamIn = new MemoryStream();
        await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(streamIn);
        fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        _logger.LogError($"Error while retrieving content resource: {path}", e);
        return NotFound();
    }  
    
    return File(fileStream, _getContentType(filename));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right to have this concern because your code is downloading the entire blob to memory before uploading it to the client. This is very inefficient.

Furthermore, you are not even using the MemoryStream where you download the file. Just delete this code:

```
streamIn = new MemoryStream();
await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(streamIn);
```

The rest of the code should stream the file from Azure and stream it to the client in parallel.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to add anything to ensure the stream is closed or will this be disposed of automatically after the flie has been served?

Comment: @kyuz0 Yes, it will close the stream automatically. Otherwise it would be very difficult for you to know when to dispose of it manually.